# Java Constructors and dot operators

Tags: java, constructor, operators

just made this account to ask a question that I am having difficulty getting the answers to online. Hopefully asking it here will help.

To summarize, I need to make a source file with two classes, a basketball class and a test class. The basketball class declares 3 class variables: name,number and team and will define two methods: dribble() and shoot().

This is where I have my confusion, the Basketball class has to have a constructor that will be used to make the objects and the tester class has to use the constructor to create the basketball player objects, use dot operator to initialize the instance variables and use the dot operator to call the methods.

I know how to make it so that parameters are used for constructors to give the instance variables values. But I'm not sure how I can make it so that I'm using constructors to create the objects and use dot operators to initialize the variables.

```
class Basketball {

    String name, team;
    int number;

    Basketball(String playerName, int playerNumber, String playerTeam) {
        name = playerName;
        number = playerNumber;
        team = playerTeam;
    }

    public void dribble() {
        System.out.println(name + ", number " + number + " from the " + team +
            " team is dribbling the ball down the court!");
    }

    public void shoot() {
        System.out.println(name + ", number " + number + " from the " + team +
            " team shoots the ball and.... scores!");
    }
}

class BasketballTester {

    public static void main(String [] args) {

        Basketball player1 = new Basketball("Michael", 23, "Chicago Bulls");
        Basketball player2 = new Basketball("LeBron", 6, "Miami Heats");
        Basketball player3 = new Basketball("Kobe", 24, "Los Angeles Lakers");
        Basketball player4 = new Basketball("Kevin", 35, "Oklahoma City Thunder");

        player1.dribble();
        player1.shoot();
        player2.dribble();
        player2.shoot();
        player3.dribble();
        player3.shoot();
        player4.dribble();
        player4.shoot();
    }
}
```

This does work but I'm not using the dot operator to initialize the instance variables. Can anybody help me out please? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean something like this?

```
Basketball player1 = new Basketball("", 1, "");
player1.name = "Joe Smith";
player1.team = "Generic Team";
player1.number = 1;
player1.shoot();
// etc...
```

It would be better to not access member variables of another class directly, though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think that is what I was looking for. Is the number 1 for an int variable equivalent to "" in a string variable? Or would 0 be it?

Comment: I'm not quite sure that you can call any integer "equivalent" to a string in Java, due to strong typing.

Comment: 1 is not equal to "", neither is 0. The closest one could come is null, but that's not possible here, since int is a primitive data type. An event better solution would be to have to constructors, one that takes name, team and number as a parameter, and one that does not.